# Is there a specific rule for a counter to go through states?

Tags: digital-logic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbZsgB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have the following circuit and I have to tell what the circuit will do?

I determined the state equations as

$$Q1(t+1)=Q1Q2'$$ and $$Q2(t+1)=Q1Q2$$

and the sequence of states I found from state table is 00, 00, 10, 01,

But the answer gven in the book is that
" A controller with a repeated sequence of 00, 01, 10" Which I think I cannot tell from the answer I have found.

So if my method is correct then how can I confirm it 
Here is my work I used A and B for FF1 and FF2[image]

Comment: Are those *toggle* flip flops?

Comment: Your state equations are incorrect. Notice that there are ORs only in the circuit and no AND.

Comment: It would be impossible in this type of state machine (with no external inputs) to repeat a state twice, then transition to another state. The next state depends only on the current state. So if the next state after 00 is 00, it would get stuck in state 00 forever.

Comment: Could you please check this question in the book by DIGITAL DESIGN by M.MORRIS MANO , MICHAEL D.CILETTI fourth edition Problem 5.8@mkeith

Comment: It is all the same which I posted here and the answer is also given@mkeith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is correct. See it in this way as soon as connections are made, and clock pulse hits the ckt. is established there would be a signal 1 to OR2 which will turn the value of Q2 will be 1 as toggle is one. 
Thus output changes from 00 to 01

On second pulse or2 remains 1 and or1 also becomes 1 thus tff1 is 1 thus output becomes Qff1 becomes 1 . Here imp. point is Tff2 is still 1 changing Qff2 to 0.
Output changes from 01 to 10.

In third cycle or1 still gives out 1 thus togggle is on and Tff1 changes to zero. As Qff1 is thus rendered 0 no toggle in Qff2 occurs.
Output changes from 10 to 00.

So on the cycle continues.